# Positioning of a resistor

Tags: sensor

Apologies in advance, my electronics knowledge is very poor.

I've got myself a resistor that I believe is appropriate for the job I want to do on my vehicle. I'm replacing the factory sensor; there are two wires going to the sensor from the car's management system.

The way I understand how it's working is that one of the wires is providing 5v to the sensor which reads a value and returns the voltage back to the ECU. I need the resistor because the curve is different to the original. The resistor required has already been calculated.

Does it matter which wire I put the resistor on?

This is the sensor: -

http://www.bmotorsports.com/shop/product_info.php/products_id/400

Comment: When you say "the curve is different to the original"; are you talking about the unloaded resistance vs temperature chart? If so, if you bought that sensor, how do you know the curve is different?

Comment: My semantics are, more than likely, off; please forgive that. There is information available on the car forum I use that has stated that a 14.2k resistor is what I need to ensure the resistance vs temperature curves match.  I'm asking here because I'd like to learn more myself.

Comment: I'll just assume the forum is right for simplicity. You ask: "which wire to put the resistor on?" which suggests the resistor is intended to be wired in series with the sensor (is this right?). In which case, it doesn't matter which wire or position from the sensor. The resistance of the resistor and the resistance of the sensor will add up the same amount.

Comment: Thanks for your assumption, I also hope that it is right. You are correct that it is to be wired in series. Perhaps you should write this in an answer as you've probably just answered my question Nick. My concern was simply which wire to put it on and if that doesn't matter when in series, then that's good. Is there somewhere I can read why this is the case?

Comment: I love sparkfun, this entire page will keep you busy for a month probably: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/analog-vs-digital/res The "Resistors" link is a pretty thorough breakdown.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought to ask a question about whether a resistor should be positioned on the annode/cathode on the mechanics stack exchange.

Comment: @Passerby The content of the question is electrical based; why does it matter if it is for an automotive application?

Comment: @Passerby So if it's not an Arduino question, it's ok to migrate it?

Comment: @matt either we are using that logic or we aren't. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: Are you replacing the sensor with this resistor, or are you trying to modify the value the computer receives? What are you trying to accomplish? Not using the sensor, or modifying the value will affect fuel air ratio and could negatively affect driveability

Comment: I am placing a new sensor that has less susceptibility to heat soak and updates much faster to change but the output of the sensor is different. Using a resistor, in series, gives me the correct output over the ranges that are important. There will be some tuning to ensure AFR is good as I'm running map sensors which, I believe, use Boyle's law to calculate volume from pressure and temperature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By our discussion we assume that:

- An external 14.2kOhm resistor is needed
- The resistor must be wired in series

From this, it will not matter the wire, nor position that the resistor is applied. The resistance will add the same.

[image: schematic]

The wires (ideally) have no resistance, so POS is arbitrary, the resistance across A and B will be the same. The fact that R1 is attached to node A is arbitrary as well.

Comment: That CircuitLab tool is very useful too! Nice one. I guess my concern was that if I placed the resistor before the sensor, with the sensor requiring 5v, it could lower the voltage that the sensor receives.

Comment: @chrisw69 If you placed the resistor after the sensor, there would still be a voltage drop across the resistor. The voltage drop across the sensor would be the exact same; regardless of the resistor being before or after sensor.